# In AS3, can a Document class extend another custom class that extends MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, actionscript, subclass, extends

If I have a Document class that extends MovieClip, and I want to use it as the basis for another Document class, is it possible to create a subclass that extends the main document class and use that for a different FLA?

For example,

fla1.fla has a document class of MyMainClass:

```
public class MyMainClass extends MovieClip
```

fla2.fla has a document class of MySubClass:

```
public class MySubClass extends MyMainClass
```

I've tried, but now I'm getting errors that all of my variables that reference stage instances aren't being found.

Comment: Are the variables that aren't being found in the parent Class or the Subclass?  Also, have you checked to make sure that "declare stage instances automatically" is off (and you've actually declared them in your Class)?

Comment: they're in the parent class. They aren't actually variables I've declared in the code, they are instance names on stage. I've tried it with "declare stage instances" both on and off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set Flash's "automatically declare stage instances", and you'll need to make sure that the parent class of the document is Dynamic. Both of those will cause the problems you're talking about.

As a side note -- because of bugs in Flash, you will have fewer issues if you declare all of your variables as public variables to begin with in your document root class.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up having to go through and add everything as public var declarations, and turn off "automatically declare." It was a bit of a pain but once I did that it worked as I hoped it would.

Comment: Note that dynamic Classes do not perform as well as normal Classes, as well as generally being considered bad practice.

Comment: @Amy In this case dynamic is the best option, especially if working with people who are not technically minded.

Comment: I would disagree, since obviously he figured out how to do it in the way that was better practice :).  It's always worthwhile to present the best practice solution, no matter how nontechnical you think the person might be.

Comment: Fine, but the original poster did not say "I'm an animator, and by implication incapable of understanding good practice." :)

Comment: I am a technical person. :-) This a small project that won't be handed off to any animators or probably even any other developers, so there isn't a whole lot of concern about performance or best practice. If I were doing a huge project with multiple developers involved and performance concerns, I would agree that the best practice wins. However reality often dictates that best practice isn't always possible or practical. Sometimes "do it now" takes precedence over "do it right"

Comment: Blanket statements about best practice and poor performance do not have any bearing on this specific scenario. Dynamic classes are a _feature_ of ActionScript 3. In this case you can use them to work around the weirdness of the authoring stage + document class combo.